# Android Value ListView Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to migrate Java to kotlin?

**Sample Code:**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String value = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
   } 
});
```

how about this?

```
String value = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

Comment: hello @suryani harja ...you should use recycler view instead of list view

Comment: press `ctrl+shift+alt+k` see the magic

Comment: use the Android Studio embedded java -> kotlin converter

Comment: how about this? String value = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

Comment: same thing - use the Android Studio embedded converter.

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like this

```
val listView:ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
```

item click listener

```
 listView.onItemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener {

            override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                            position: Int, id: Long) {

                // value of item that is clicked

      val value = (view as? TextView)?.text.toString()

            }
        }
```

**Note** : I strongly recommend using recyclerview instead

Comment: how about this? 
String value = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet !!
`val value = (view as? TextView)?.text.toString()`